# Is conditional logic limited to items in a section in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

My question is about the behavior of conditional logic within sections.

How do you reference a field outside of the section?  It does not show in basic editor, and I do not know how to access these via the advanced editor.

This is the error I get when I type in the name of a field inside another section using the advanced editor:

[image]

Replicating this in a field that is not in a section works just fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can definitely access fields in other sections in [Cognito Forms](https://www.cognitoforms.com).

You need to reference the top level form as well as possibly a section name.

```
=Form.Section1.OtherField
```

Here is a link to documentation describing how to do this when using the advanced editor for calculations:

https://www.cognitoforms.com/support/2/calculations